# AttributeError: module 'pandas_ml' has no attribute 'imbaccessors'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

i try to import lib pandas_ml using pip and using .whl file

but i get the following error 
AttributeError: module 'pandas_ml' has no attribute 'imbaccessors'
can any one tell me how can i fix this error